# Altering inspector custom ribbon controls dynamiccaly

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, ribbon-control

In my Outlook add-in, I assign a custom ribbon (a new group with controls) to the inspectors initially to support some functionalities for some mails that I create manually. This custom tab is being displayed when I open every mail item regardless the store or folder. I wantto make this tab visible only for the inspectors of the custom mail items I manually create.

Following is a fragment of the xml of which I add as the custom UI for inspectors in code. I have added a callback method to get executed to set the visibility (**GetCustomGroupVisible**).

```
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabReadMessage">
        <group id="MyCustomGroup"  insertBeforeMso="GroupMailDelete" getVisible="GetCustomGroupVisible">
          <button id="Button1" size="large" onAction="ButtonClick" />
          <button id="Button2" size="large" onAction="ButtonClick" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>


 // Callback method
 public bool GetCustomGroupVisible(IRibbonControl control)
 {
     bool makeVisible = false;           
     if ( // this is one of my custom mails !)
      {
        makeVisible = true;
      }
      return makeVisible;
  }
```

My problem is, the above shown callback method "**GetCustomGroupVisible**" is not being called sometimes when I open a new inspector. Why is this happening like that ? What should I do to have this callback method executed each time I open a new inspector. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to force ribbon update when NewInspector event fires. Call IRibbonUI.Invalidate. IRibbonUI can be retrieved from the OnLoad ribbon callback (must be specified in the ribbon XML).